# Хотел написать простую функцию с использованием Math.random которая заполнила бы мне массив случайными числами в заданном диапазоне. Не работает

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Laba1_8 {

    private static void rand(int[]mass) {
        System.out.print("Massive:");
        for (int i = 1; i == mass.length-1;) {
            mass[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 201) - 100;
            System.out.printf(" %d", mass[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter size of massive: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int size= sc.nextInt();
        int[]array=new int[size];
        rand(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не следует изменять смысл вопроса, он не будет из-за этого переоткрыт. Задайте просто новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш счетчик `i` в цикле `for` имеет условие, которое всегда будет давать `false`, и отсутствует какое-либо изменение счетчика `i`.

Попробуйте изменить условия цикла на такие:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
```